# Error: Permission denied to access property of subdomain

Tags: javascript, permissions, subdomain

I am loading pages from an iFrame, and of course I get this error: 
Error: Permission denied to access property "INSERT JAVASCRIPT VARIABLE HERE".

The main frame of the website is www.domain.com

The iFrame I am using to access pages are loading from domain: www.localserver.centralserver.domain.com

Why can't I do this setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access JS objects bound to page from other domain. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy